# Wordpress Tags - How to obtain all the posts with the same tag

Tags: wordpress

I need to obtain all the posts that have the same tag. But I have the difficult situation that Ive created a new post type called video (instead of post i create videos)

When I make
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC','post_type' => 'video');

$blablabla = query_posts($args);

I have a result, but when I add the 'tag'=>'whatevertag' I dont receive anything. Do you know why have i got this problem?

Thanks for all

Comment: I saw this kind of problem solutions in Wordpress Support. There you can search and find something. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-taxonomy-and-query_posts http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-posts-by-tag-and-custom-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you think about using instead meta_key or meta_value modify the custom_post to use category?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID

$catId = get_cat_ID($categoryname);

and then in the args of the query insert 'category'=>$catId

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use a custom type and for custom types you use custom tags. You need to use meta_key and meta_value.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query_post-by-meta_key-only-without-specific-category-setting-not-works

Comment: Thanks, but the problem of that is that you need to configure for every custom post these defaults, and i prefer to use tags or categories because for the user is easier